# Case Statement for Joined Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
Account ID | A | B
-------------------
1          | x | y
2          | c | f
3          |...|...
```

the first table is a general account list. The second table is a list of documents on hand for each acct:

```
Account ID | Doctype
---------------------
1          | chrgoff
2          | dtpmnt
2          | chrgoff
3          | lstpmt
3          | suit
```

For the report I'm creating, I need to create a column in the first table which stores the value of a flag, where 'Y' indicates that the second table contains the docType 'chrgoff' for a given account number.

I tried doing this with the following case statement, but the query won't execute at all:

```
'chgoff' = 
    CASE
      WHEN EXISTS(SELECT docType FROM table2 WHERE docType='chrgoff' and AccountID=table1.accountID) 
      THEN 'Y'
      ELSE 'N'
   END
```

I'm very new to T-SQL programming, so I would appreciate any help I could get! Let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use a `CASE` **expression** in the `WHERE` (or `ON`), just boolean logic.

Comment: Thanks for clarrifying - how would you do it differently?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. The full query would help.

Answer (score 2):

You code looks okay, but I would suggest:

```
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT docType FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.docType = 'chrgoff' and t2.AccountID = table1.accountID) 
      THEN 'Y'
      ELSE 'N'
 END) as chgoff
```

The main differences are:

- No single quotes on the column name.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- Qualify the column references in the subquery.  Don't depend on SQL's scoping rules.  Be explicit.

As for `as` versus `=`.  I prefer the former because it is standard SQL; `=` only assigns column aliases in SQL Server and related databases.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way - You can flag a record by joining both the tables with `left outer join`. I believe it would be faster approach than `EXIST` with `subquery`.

SQL -

```
select t1.*, 
case when t2.account_id is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as chgoff
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.account_id = t2.account_id and t2.doctype = 'chrgoff'
```